# How to run .php script on node.js

Tags: php, node.js

I'm using wamp server and node.js to run my app(server.js), but when I want to execute .php script I always got an error: 
`POST http://localhost:8080/login.php 404 (Not Found)`

**server.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var webRTC = require('webrtc.io').listen(server);
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
server.listen(port);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/login.php', function(req, res){
exec("wget -q -O - http://localhost/login.php", function (error, stdout, stderr) {res.send(stdout);});});
```

in **index.html** calls to login.php:

```
$("#login").click(function(){
  username=$("#user_name").val();
  password=$("#password").val();
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "login.php",
      data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
      success: function(html)
               {......
```

I want to ask,  it's neccessary to install another tool or something else ?

thank you.

Comment: have you tried doing app.post instead of get? your form is sending a http post.

Comment: I try to test this code:
`http://tutsforweb.blogspot.sk/search/label/ajax`

Answer (score 8):

Node.js won't execute your PHP code, the Apache server will.
As I understand your question you have an Apache server listening on port 80 and a Node.js server listening on 8080 and you want the HTML page served by Node.js to perform an Ajax post on the Apache served login.php. If this assertion is true then the problem is that your Ajax request point to localhost:8080 instead of localhost:80.

You must give an absolute URL to the Ajax request parameters to correctly point to the Apache server (port 80), giving a relative URL as you do it right now will perform the request to localhost:8080 which is your Node.js server.

So, replacing:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "login.php",
  data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
```

by

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:80/login.php",
  data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
```

should do the trick.

You certainly want to get the server address from the actual page which you can do like this in JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: window.location.href.replace(/^(https?:\/\/[^\/]+/,'$1:80/') + "login.php",
  data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
```

Comment: actually, now I got an error:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/login.php. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: you have now to check about Access-Control policy headers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS Your apache web server must return good headers to allow cross domain requests

Answer (score 2):

To install to Node.js:

```
npm install node-php
```

**Usage**

To run WordPress with Node.js and Express, do this:

```
var express = require('express');
var php = require("php");
var path = require("path");

var app = express();

app.use("/", php.cgi("/path/to/wordpress"));

app.listen(9090);

console.log("Server listening!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the routing using Express methods app object that correspond to HTTP methods.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})
```