# How can I pass a value from Node Js to php then return back?

Tags: php, node.js, parameter-passing

I have a php file and Node API. The php file in server which return the random number by user given max value. The user given maximun value is given from Node Js to php. Then the php returns the random value, then the values should be save in MongoDB

**php code**

```
<?php
    $min = 1111;
    $max = '';  // This is given by user from Node API

    $number = mt_rand($min, $max); //Generate a random number using the rand function.

    echo $number;
?>
```

**Node API**

```
router.post("/findMax", upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next)
{
  var enteredMaxNum = req.body.maxNum;
  if(!enteredMaxNum)
  {
    return res.status(400).send("Maximum number should be given");
  }

  const objNumber = new Number(
    {
      max : enteredMaxNum,  // User given, should pass to php variable
      randNum : ????,       // php file return value
    });

    objNumber.save((err) =>
      {
        if (err)
        {
          console.log("New Error : " + err);
          return next(err);
        }
        res.status(201).send("Numbers saved");
      });
})
```

Comment: you should connect to your server (with the php script) from within your node code and pass the value

Comment: How can I connect the php script with Node?

Comment: for examples take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298161/how-to-run-php-script-on-node-js

Comment: btw why do you need to use php for this? and not do everything in node?

Comment: Actually the php is used to send SMS by given SMS gateway with generating random number. There is no option to send SMS by Node .

Comment: And as your above link, how to pass the values?

Comment: Is there any solutions ?

Comment: This is an XY post, Post has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661805/does-not-work-passing-values-to-php-from-node-js-and-back , OP lacks basic knowledge of both Javascript and PHP

Comment: The OP had just started to learn by do for Node Js and php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did not you use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). Try this code hopefully will work as you want

**node**

```
router.post("/findMax", upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next)
{
  var enteredMaxNum = req.body.maxNum;
  if(!enteredMaxNum)
  {
    return res.status(400).send("Maximum number should be given");
  }

  axios.post('your-php-file-path', require('querystring').stringify({getNodeNum: enteredMaxNum}))
  .then(response => {
    if (response)
    {
      const objNumber = new Number({max: enteredMaxNum, randNum: response.data.random});
      objNumber.save((err) => {
        if (err)
        {
          console.log("New Error : " + err);
          res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.status(201).send("Numbers saved");
        });
    }
      })
  .catch(error => res.status(500).send(error));
})
```

**php**

```
<?php

    $min = 1111;

    if(isset($_POST['getNodeNum'])) // It should be $_POST
    {
        $max = $_POST['getNodeNum'];

        $number = mt_rand($min, $max);

        print(json_encode(['random' => $number]));
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you got it the idea. Perfect using of axios.